# mu4e: do not display messages in the thread that does not respect the query

Tags: mu4e

It seems that when I do a search like `date:2d..now AND NOT flag:trashed`, mu4e display all the messages that respect the query... but also some others that are in the same thread (here I got some deleted messages).

It can be really practical to follow a discussion, however it can be a problem when I want to do a specific operation on them (like select all the lower part of the screen and move them to a specific directory)... Any idea how I could disable these messages that should not be there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I found the answer [here](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Other-search-functionality.html#Other-search-functionality): type `W`, or set `mu4e-headers-include-related` to `nil`.

Comment: This worked for me. Can you accept your own answer?